# Cordova File Transfer to Node Server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova

I'm using the ng-Cordova fileTransfer plugin to try to upload a photo from the user's camera roll to a Node/Express server.

I'm getting the local URI of a photo and trying to pass it to the plugin as such:

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://135.23.98.169:8069/upload_avatar', fileURI)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        console.log('success');
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log('what');
                    });
```

The server endpoint is reached, but `req.files` is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Express 4 or above? http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.properties

Comment: opticon, can you share your code from your solution (client and server)?  i'm trying to get multer to work with cordovaFileTransfer and having no luck.  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Express 4.x, you have to include the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware to enable multipart data. After you've done that, the file will available in `req.files`