# NodeJs Server implementation for uploading multipart

Tags: node.js, swift3, multipartform-data

My Swift 3 client code:

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        let path = "\(Bundle.main.resourcePath!)/images"
        let all = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: URL(string: path)!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

        let filtered = all!.filter { $0.pathExtension == "jpg" }
        for item in filtered {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: item.path, isDirectory: false)
            multipartFormData.append(url, withName: item.path)
        }

    }, to: "http://localhost:3000/upload") {
        (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

My server code:

```
app.post('/upload', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.files)
  res.send('{"status":"ok"}')
})
```

But the req.files is undefined. I'm wondering what the cause is. How to implement the NodeJs?

**Edit on 26/6/2017 (solved!):**

By following Svenskunganka's suggestion, I added multer to my NodeJs code:

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files)
  res.send('{"status":"ok"}')
})
```

My swift code:

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        let path = "\(Bundle.main.resourcePath!)/images"
        let all = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: URL(string: path)!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

        let filtered = all!.filter { $0.pathExtension == "jpg" }
        for item in filtered {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: item.path, isDirectory: false)
            multipartFormData.append(url, withName: "photos", fileName: url.lastPathComponent, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

    }, to: "http://localhost:3000/upload") {
        (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

Then it works fine. One thing to remember, the number **12** in `upload.array('photos', 12)` is the max number of multiparts will be uploaded. If the number is greater than 12, then will get a "Undefined" error in server.

Comment: You have to install the multer middleware in Express, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949902/cordova-file-transfer-to-node-server/29949951#29949951

Comment: Looks good. But don't know how to use Multer. Got Error: Unexpected field when I add "upload.array('photos', 12)" to my nodejs code. I don't know where to add fieldname "photos" in my swift code. Any idea?